# TCP -- How can I tell if a segment belongs to HTTP Request or HTTP Response message?

Tags: networking, tcp

This is more of a conceptual question than a coding question. With a TCP segment, how do I know if it belongs to HTTP Request or HTTP Response message? Will the header somehow tell me?

Comment: By the direction it is going in, of course.

Comment: TCP doesn't really care about the contents of it payload, e.g. HTTP. That way it can carry any number of application-layer protocols, even those not yet invented.